# Django models and auto created tables

Tags: sql, django, models

I'm using django for my project, its all going well except its table handling.

Autocreated tables are great for people who don't want to make raw queries and are not interested in adding and deleting columns. But for me, I want to have complete control over my database.

```
class Partner(models.Model):
    software = models.ManyToManyField(Software)
```

This creates:

- `partner_partner`
- `partner_partner_software`

Second table to handle manytomany relation. 
This kind of behaviour makes it complicated for me to observe and understand my table structure.
I think this allows me to do it:

```
partner = Partner.objects.get(pk=1)
software = partner.software
```

if I don't use manytomany like relations and instead of above usage,

```
partner = Partner.objects.get(pk=1)
software = Software.objects.get(name = partner.software)
```

You think using this kind of technique is the best choice in this case?

Comment: You don't want to hear my answer. Although I will upvote anyone that can put it a nicer way.

Comment: Regarding auto-created tables:  The Django syncdb only auto-generates tables that don't already exist.  So if a table matching your model's name already exists, and one side changes, it is the developer's responsibility to sufficiently re-synchronize the model and table.  Theoretically, you could use the DB table as your primary representation, and then just manually tweak the Django model to 'follow' the table when necessary, enough so that Django doesn't complain.  Whether doing it this way is wise or not is debatable.

Comment: For someone who claims to want complete control over your relations, you seem to be very confused about what a many-to-many relationship is (hint: it's not a 1-to-many relation, aka ForeignKey).

Comment: I actually said control over my tables and I m not django expert but I think these extra tables are created to manage relations. these extra tables have information like .
'1', '1', '1' '2', '2', '2'. Its just not comprehensible.

Answer (score -2):

I used Django and I have complete control over my tables. I just set it up in a way that it lets Django handle the CMS part and CodeIgniter handles the site.

Comment: manytomany field just creates partner_partner_software like tables in my example and it has a content like.
'1', '1', '1'
'2', '2', '2'
How do you manage it? just avoid using these relations?

Comment: Yes, I avoid that completely. I build my tables in MySQL and then import then into Django.